# CDI @Resource field injection is not throwing exception

Tags: java, dependency-injection, weblogic, cdi

I'm using CDI @Resource field injection (for data sources). When there is any problem with that injection (name not found, etc) I don't get any exception or log.

How to get that exception or log?

Efren V.

Comment: What logs are you looking at? Both the server.out and server.log file? Have you turned up the logging level to debug for your server in the admin console via `servers->server name->logging tab->advanced`

Comment: What version of weblogic are you using? I know that this works on other app servers just fine (WildFly).  Perhaps you should create an SR.

Comment: I'm using WebLogic 12.1.1